# Azure Data Factory Error 'item' is not a recognized function

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have the following REST configuration in Azure Data Factory

[image]

As you can I'm getting the error:

'item' is not a recognized function

The full configuration is

```
convert?q=USD_@{item().Currency}&compact=ultra&apiKey=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Do I need to configure @item in Parameters?

The guide suggests I need to following these steps
[image]

Comment: item() used in a ForEach activity in ADF. Do you want to copy data from Each REST API page? and also what is the value of item().Currency?

Comment: can u please provide more info about your pipeline? which activities are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your code in the dynamic context, you are using this REST resource inside a ForEach as above it has `item()` function. You can get **item().<"Value">** in a ForEach using a lookup.

`item()` is a ***ForEach function and can be used inside a ForEach which is used inside a ADF pipeline***. You are using the **ForEach function inside Dataset which is not known for the dataset**. ***That's why it is giving a warning***. When you use that dataset only for that pipeline it will give you the result without any error. **But for any other pipeline It will give you the warning as error**.

To use a pipeline function in the Dataset, the best practice is to create a Dataset parameter and give the value for this in the pipeline like below.

**Create a Dataset Parameter with string type and a Default value:**

[image]

**Give this parameter in the Dataset dynamic context:**

[image]

**Now you can give pipeline function values for this Parameter inside ForEach or inside Pipeline:**

Here I have used Copy activity for sample and given the value as per my URL. You can give your Relative URL with `item()` function in dynamic context.

[image]

Based on the `item().Currency` values it will give the REST page URL in each iteration.

Comment: Hi RakeshGovindula, thanks for reaching out. Can you take a look at my update and explain why the author suggest I follow his steps if he / she knew it would fail?

Comment: @Patterson, the approach which you are following is good only when you are using the above dataset for that particular kind of pipelines where a ForEach involved. It will give you the desired results when you debug the pipeline, but the best practice is to create a parameter for the dataset and provide the pipeline function value to it inside the pipeline. This gives you the flexibility to give the dynamic value that you want which required for different pipelines.

Comment: Hi Rakesh, that is great advice.